# Ubuntu 22.04: permanently enable Bluetooth file reception?

Tags: bluetooth, gnome-shell, 22.04

I often use Bluetooth to quickly send a file from my phone to my laptop. On Ubuntu 22.04 with the default Gnome Shell, this means I first have to open the Settings -> Bluetooth dialog and leave it open before I can receive files. Is there any way to enable this feature permanently?

(I'm aware the current behaviour is for security reasons, but I know which devices I've paired with my laptop, so I'd be OK with auto-reception.)

EDIT: I know this can be worked around by using blueman, but that brings its own set of issues, so I'd rather use the standard gnome-shell tools.

Answer (score 2):

***Workaround***

you can install package `blueman` with the command `sudo apt install blueman`

```
$ apt search blueman
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
blueman/bionic,now 2.0.5-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
  Graphical bluetooth manager

$ apt show blueman
Package: blueman
Version: 2.0.5-1ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/x11
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Christopher Schramm <debian@shakaweb.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 5,023 kB
Depends: libbluetooth3 (>= 4.91), libc6 (>= 2.4), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8), libpython3.6 (>= 3.6.0~b2), dconf-gsettings-backend | gsettings-backend, python3 (<< 3.7), python3 (>= 3.6~), python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~), dbus, bluez (>= 4.61), obexd-client (>= 0.47) | bluez-obexd, obexd-server (>= 0.47) | bluez-obexd, python3-dbus, python3-gi, notification-daemon, librsvg2-common, gnome-icon-theme, libpulse-mainloop-glib0, gir1.2-gtk-3.0, gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0, gir1.2-glib-2.0, gir1.2-pango-1.0, gir1.2-notify-0.7, python3-cairo, python3-gi-cairo, gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1
Recommends: policykit-1, pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
Homepage: https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman
Task: xubuntu-desktop, lubuntu-gtk-desktop, lubuntu-desktop, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntukylin-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop
Supported: 3y
Download-Size: 1,686 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
Description: Graphical bluetooth manager
 Blueman is a GTK+ bluetooth management utility for GNOME using bluez D-Bus
 backend.

maduri@i7-4770:~$
```

2. run `blueman-services`
3. tick the button "Accept files from Trusted Devices"

[image]

Comment: solves the issue. I wonder what the downvote was for?

Answer (score 0):

Hacked together a self-made solution in the form of a Python script that runs in the background and just accepts all connections via DBus messages: https://gist.github.com/floe/47fa5b33da71f1a637b60a53a24cd549